# How does boto choose aws region to create buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I created 3 different buckets, 1 using aws management console and 2 using boto api.

Bucket created using aws management console was created in tokyo region whereas the one created using boto were created us-east-1 region.

When I access by bucket using boto how does it findout the correct region in which the buckets are created. Also, how does it choose which region to create bucket in.

I have gone thought the connection.py file in boto source code but I am not able to make any sense of the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the location of a new bucket by specifying a value for the `location` parameter in the `create_bucket` method.  For example, to create a bucket in the `ap-northeast-1` region you would do this:

```
import boto.s3
from boto.s3.connection import Location
c = boto.s3.connect_to_region('ap-northeast-1')
bucket = c.create_bucket('mynewbucket', location=Location.APNortheast)
```

In this example, I am connecting to the S3 endpoint in the `ap-northeast-1` region but that is not required.  Even if you are connected to the universal S3 endpoint you can still create a bucket in another location using this technique.

To access the bucket after it has been created, you have a couple of options:

- You could connect to the S3 endpoint in the region you created the bucket and then use the `get_bucket` method to lookup your bucket and get a `Bucket` object for it.
- You could connect to the universal S3 endpoint and use the `get_bucket` method to lookup your bucket.  In order for this to work, you need to follow the more restricted bucket naming conventions described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html).  This allows your bucket to be accessed via `virtual hosting` style addressing, e.g. https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/.  This, in turn, allows DNS to resolve your request to the correct S3 endpoint.  Note that the DNS records take time to propagate so if you try to address your bucket in this manner immediately after it has been create it might not work.  Try again in a few minutes.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the reply! I went through the documentation and s3/connection.py file again and found that by default it create buckets in US Standard region. I am trying to learn how boto is implemented and how to design bindings for REST API, could you please provide me some direction on this. I am stuck at implementation of Authentication Signature Algorithm V4. I am not able to exactly understand how to create the URIs and authenticated requests. Please provide some pointer on concepts I should be studying before trying this out! Thanks for the reply, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: To be honest, if you are looking for models to follow I would focus on botocore rather than boto.  The botocore package is already compatible with 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3 and is a much cleaner implementation since its  a fresh start.

Comment: Is this answer correct? Using `boto 2`, I am able to successfully call `get_bucket()` to get the bucket regardless of what region it was created in. I do not need to call `connect_to_region()` first.